# self.navigationController pushViewController: animated: gives me a black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using Objective-C. I have this code in my .m file.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    detailViewController *detail = [[detailViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

And I created my Detail View Controller Scene in storyboard. It looks like this [[image]

And every time I run this in my simulator and tap on one of the tableview cell, it pushes the screen to a complete black screen like this:

[image]

Can someone help me? I would thank you very much!

Comment: Apparently your application has stopped because it coudn't load a nib file. Why don't you share the error message with us?

Comment: Why don't you use segue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will give a blank screen, because you haven't attached any visual interpretation on `detailViewController` class.

Use this method

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
DetailViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

You will have to set storyboard id by clicking on view controller and set storyboard id as shown in picture

[image]

Note : for above pic replace Storyboard id "MessagingVC" with "detailViewController"

Comment: If the current view controller was loaded from the same storyboard, you want to use `self.storyboard` instead of loading it afresh.

Comment: @Usama, instead of setting "MessagingVC" Storyboard ID in identity inspector, it should be "detailViewController" as is calling in code.

Comment: yes it should be, i just attached the pic of the screen which was currently opened on my pc, just to give an idea. Updated the answer, thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 0):

When using a storyboard, you don't want to use `alloc+init` to create the view controller.  Instead, you need to assign a Storyboard ID in Interface Builder and then use:

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:my_identifier];
```

A better option may be to set a push segue on the table view controller.  This will cause the instantiation and push to happen automatically.  You can override `prepareForSegue:sender:` to set properties, if needed.